# Android Does admob use cache? How Cache works?

Tags: android

I have this aplication thats keeps building cache every time I open the app

In my app I load like 20 images from my website, but I don't save them to cache,
does the app automatically save this images to cache? If so, I don't think they load from cache, cuz I still have to have internet to load them

Admob in the other hand, if I don't have internet and I loaded the test ad before, it will load the testad.

currently I have the app to delete the cache everytime it starts, keeping cache low, but this doesn't seems smart.

My questions are:

- Does admob uses cache of my app?
- Knowing my app loads 20 images from my website, this images being
  loaded affects my cache size even if I don't save them
  programmatically to cache ?
- is deleting cache expensive enough to have a dedicated thread to
  do just that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. **Does admob uses cache of my app?**

Yes i think Admob caches its ads so they load faster. And Admob should be managing its own cache size. I don't think you need to worry about that.

2. **Knowing my app loads 20 images from my website, this images being loaded affects my cache size even if I don't save them
   programmatically to cache ?**

No images or bitmaps will not be cached unless you do so, see this [link](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/graphics/cache-bitmap.html) for more info. I will recommend that you use the Glide or Picasso for image loading since they are memory efficient and abstract out most of the complexity.

3. **Is deleting cache expensive enough to have a dedicated thread to do just that?**

I don't think you should use dedicated thread. What you can do is override `onTrimMemory` and keep monitoring the memory level.When your memory level is critical or low you can delete the cache. Check this [link](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/memory.html) for more info. In my opinion if you use Glide for loading your images it will already handle the memory very well and prevents OutOfMemoryError. Also, loads image much faster.